# How can I copy and paste formatted text in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, copy-paste

Before I ask question, I've searched but only found ways of copy and paste "formatted cell". That's not what I need.

I want to use an example to explain my requirement:

1. There are 2 cells in a sheet.
2. Cell_A's text is "aaaaabbbbb", and "aaaaa" is green, and "bbbbb" is red.
3. Cell_B's text is "ccccc" and "ccccc" is black.
4. I want to copy and paste "bbbbb" from Cell_A to Cell_B and keep "bbbbb" in red. But in my environment(Office 2007), "bbbbb" is changed to black as "ccccc", the default format of Cell_B.

Is there an easy way to implement my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Normal way to copy formatted text in Microsoft Office Applications:

- Select the example text/cell with the wanted format.
- Click on the **Format Painter**.
- Finally select the text/cell which you want to paste format.

Confirmed Here: [More information about this topic provide by Microsoft Office Support](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/quickly-copy-formatting-with-the-format-painter-HA001054892.aspx).

---

#### Closest to what you asked:

- Select the *source* the cell (not the text)
- Copy it
- Select the *destination* the cell
- Click the *down arrow* under **Paste** from the *Home* tab of the ribbon bar
- Select **Keep Source Formatting** right under the *Paste* heading

What you are trying to do may not be completely possible. That is probably the closest you will get to what you are asking.

Comment: Although it doesn't fix my issue, I want to say thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

solution is very simple

copy your desired cells
paste at distination, you will find a small tag at the right bottom of pasted cells.
by clicking the tag you will several option for your pasted cells.
now click on "Match Distination Formitting".
I think your problem solved.
(Office 2007)

Answer (score 0):

You should try `right_click -> paste special` and check if any of those options works for you. I tried your example and had no problems with a normal paste...